# Need Different Colors For Graphs which are coming as black

Tags: d3.js

I need different colors for 3 graph which is shows in black color. 
But rest parts color will be same for three.
How to solve that issue.

Code here:

```
 var dataset = {
 apples: [33, 70],
 oranges: [12, 80],
lemons: [20, 90],
};

var width = 660,
height = 500,
 cwidth = 35;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#000000", "#f5f5f5"]);//Colors 

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 3 + "," + height / 3 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
.data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.pie); })//Returning color from here
.enter().append("path")
 .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
.attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(4+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth* (j+1))(d); });
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235)?

Comment: Yes i have seen it. I need 3 color for 3 different circle. I can apply diffenent color for differnt graph value in one circle

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. How does the code you've posted not work for you?

Comment: If you ran my code u can see three black arc are there. i need different color for those 3 black arcs.

Comment: Works if you use a colour scale -- http://jsfiddle.net/NpPjm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
  var i=0;
  var RamdomColor=function(col){
  var colorsArray = ['#f5f5f5', 'red', 'blue', 'green'];
   if(col == 0){
     ++i
    return colorsArray[i];
   }
   else
 return colorsArray[0];

 }

  var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");

  var path = gs.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d,i) { return pie(d); })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return RamdomColor(i);})
        .attr("transform", "translate(100,100) rotate(270 50 50)") 
        .attr("d", function(d, i,j) { return arc.innerRadius(4+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth* (j+1))(d); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've turned you code into this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EQIqizA/1/).  There were a number of things wrong with it and these are commented in the code. I've also tidied up the code a bit it was difficult to read.

The reason you were getting black circles was because you were trying to get a colour with an undefined attribute in this line `style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.pie); })`.  You were also only had 2 colours defined in `var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#000000", "#f5f5f5"]);` so it would have been impossible to get three colours.

Comment: If i gave More than two color then also it takes first two colors. So only i give in that way.

Comment: That was because you were passing the the i index which only had 2 elements (as in Lars example).  If you passed the j index you would have got 3 colours (as in my example).